# K8 pods evicted: ephemeral-storage low on resource

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have my jenkins slave configured as a kubernetes cluster nodes.

Now when I m trying to run jobs which uses docker (building images) the pods are being evicted with the following error.

The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container jnlp was using 3100Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

```
Capacity:
    cpu:                6
    ephemeral-storage:  52417516Ki
    hugepages-1Gi:      0
    hugepages-2Mi:      0
    memory:             32927516Ki
    pods:               110
Allocatable:
    cpu:                6
    ephemeral-storage:  48307982666
    hugepages-1Gi:      0
    hugepages-2Mi:      0
    memory:             32825116Ki
    pods:               110
    
Allocated resources:
    (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
    Resource           Requests      Limits
    --------           --------      ------
    cpu                100m (1%)     100m (1%)
    memory             8242Mi (25%)  8242Mi (25%)
    ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
    hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
    hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
```

In the kubelet config.yml I do not ahve any configuration for ephemeral-storage.
df -h gives a 15% of the disk free (around 7GB)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? Please attach your yaml files and write how did you set up your jenkins.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak: I did not set up the jenkins and so i m unsure of the setup. The jenkins master is on a VM as well as the nodes from some cloud provider. Jenkins master  k8 version: v1.21.3
node version: v1.22.0 and  v1.21.3

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor: the problem still persists

Comment: Can you add information about the used disk space to the question, but divided into partitions? It is possible that the root partition has no free space and the error is caused by it.